# Draw image with transparency multiplied by a color using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw an image with transparency multiplied by a color.
The only way I found is to prepare an image multiplied by color in off-screen canvas like this:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"; // copy pixel-to-pixel source image
ctx.drawImage(image, ...);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; // multiply it by red color
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; 
ctx.fillRect(...);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop"; // restore transparency
ctx.drawImage(image, ...);
```

and then draw it to necessary canvas.

Is there a better (faster) way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way to do it if you want to multiply the semi-transparent image without any background.

If the background on the "necessary canvas" directly under the image is transparent you could multiply it in place.

A couple of notes:

- `globalCompositeOperation="multiply"` is not available in Internet Explorer
- `globalCompositeOperation="copy"` seems unnecessary.

Comment: `globalCompositeOperation="copy"` has to be used when using the code block in a loop, for example.